# Mongoose function shows variable as undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Been staring at this for awhile and not sure why it is not working. I am trying to create an object within an embedded object, however, it seems like I am not passing the params down correctly as it says listings[j] is undefined. What do I need to pass into that piece for it to work?

```
function createBid(req, res) {
  //get current listing object info
  db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    // console.log(foundListing._id );
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
    }
    res.json(foundListing);
    // get array of all users
    db.User.find({}, function(err, users) {
      // for loop iterates through all users' listings
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var listings = users[i].listings
        // for loop iterates through all listings ids
        for (var j = 0; j < listings.length; j++) {
          // finds match 
          // comparing _id with _id returning false. Not sure why, will return later
          if (listings[j].topic === foundListing.topic && listings[j].created === foundListing.created) {
            console.log("Found match: " + foundListing.topic);
            // get current user id to add to bid object
            db.User.findById(req.user, function(err, user) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              var newBid = new db.Bid(req.body); // add data validation later
              newBid.uid = user._id
              // pushes new bid object into embedded listing 
              listings[j].bids.push(newBid);
              listings[j].save(function(err, savedBid) {
                console.log('newBid created: ', newBid);
                res.json(newBid);
              });
            });
          }
        }
      }
    })
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: `var` is not block-scoped (it is scoped to the function), meaning that the values of `i` and `j` are not what you are going to expect them to be once your inner db.User.findById callback is executed. If possible try using `let` instead of `var` in your for loops. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions

Comment: @vox Making some progress. After changing it to `let` I am seeing the console log of bid created, but am now getting this new error. `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: That error is due to you calling `res.json` twice, once near the top with `foundListing`, and then second with `newBid`.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the top res.json and got it to push without error, but now I am not seeing the newly created bid.  Could it be when I assigned the listings variable that it is not being pushed to the right place?